# Training keras model with variable input size

Tags: python, keras

I'm making a text analysis machine. Obviously with different sizes each vector, for example:

```
vectorA = [1, 43, 453, 22, 776, 873, 985]
vectorB = [0, 324, 32432]
```

I do not want to fix an input size, but I do not know how can the model has different input sizes?
By the way, the model is:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, ))

emb1 = keras.layers.Embedding(
    input_dim=len(X_train), 
    output_dim=None,
    )(inputs)

con1 = keras.layers.Conv1D(
    activation='relu',
    )(emb1)

pool1 = keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(
    )(con1)

output = keras.layers.Dense(4, 
                           activation="softmax")

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I'm new to `Keras` so I would appreciate any type of help!